# PHP Number of Times Word Appears

Tags: php, match

I'm trying to learn some PHP and have something I've got quite stuck on.

I'm using SOAP. Is it possible for me to match a word to what's in the array and then output a the number of times that word was displayed in the array?

I currently have this which outputs what I want to match to, but I can't seem to find a way to show how many times a word appears.

```
$facilities = $message->Facilities->FacilityInfo;

foreach ($facilities as $data) {
    echo $data->Name."<br>";
}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Using something like [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) perhaps?

Comment: if you want to do with foreach, use if() and a counter ..

Comment: I've tried using array_count_values() but I just get a 0 or 1 for each word, when I just want the total as a number, would you have an example of how I would go about using the if() and counter?

Comment: It looks like the code you've provided is just showing us that you have the Name, not what string you want to check for within each Name? What have you tried for checking the string? Do you even want to check for a particular name, or just see how many of each name there are?

Comment: Can you show your array_count_values usage?

Comment: If you get a 0 from array_count_values(), then you're doing something very, very wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Niranjan pointed out, you can use an if statement in the loop and count specific words.

```
$cnt = array();
foreach ($facilities as $data) {
    if ($data->Name == "Jan") $cnt++; // the best given name ever ;-)
    echo $data->Name."<br>";
}
echo "Count of Jan: " . $cnt;
```

As an alternative, if the whole `$facilities` array consists of words only, you could do a more abstract approach:

```
$cnt = array();
$facilities = ['Jan', 'Ben', 'Jan', 'Agathe', 'Christine', 'Jan'];
foreach ($facilities as $name) {
    $cnt[$name]++;
    echo $name."<br>";
}
print_r($cnt);
// array("Jan" => 3, "Ben" => 1, "Agathe" => 1, "Christine" => 1);
```

Besides my narcisstic personality disorder (counting me a couple of times, that is ;-)), this might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<?php
$searchWord = 'search';
$message = "search search no yes maybe works";
$words = explode(" ", $message);

if (in_array($searchWord,$words)) {
   $cntArray =  array_count_values($words);
   echo $cntArray[$searchWord] . " $searchWord word count";
}

?>
```